# How to force GeneratedCell -> True for non-editable cells?

Tags: front-end, cells

If I generate an arbitrary non-editable cell:

```
ExpressionCell[1, "Output", Editable -> False, GeneratedCell -> True]
```

And then try to edit it, the GeneratedCell option is automatically set to False. How to prevent it? I want it always to be rewritten if a cell is regenerated again.

I've tried more options without luck:

```
CellPrint@
 ExpressionCell[1, "Output", Editable -> False, GeneratedCell -> True,
   CellAutoOverwrite -> True, CellEditDuplicate -> False]
```

CellAutoOverwrite is also forcibly set to False.
Something that kinda worked is making an event action that sets it:

```
CellEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", "a"} :> 
   SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], GeneratedCell -> True, 
    CellAutoOverwrite -> True]}
```

Or maybe some scheduled task, but it's too hacky.

Comment: Have you thought about setting `Selectable -> False`? This prevents any user interaction with the cell and the options don't get changed ...

Comment: @Domen Yes, but it has to be selectable in my case. It's an interactive widget with controls and all that. I just find it annoying that it's always making a new cell when the input cell is rerun.

Comment: Can you describe the context, why do you need GeneratedCell for example? Interacting with Sliders and InputFields does not change the GeneratedCell option.

Comment: @Kuba I have Graphics that a user can draw on. But it can be anything, this problem happens with any control if a key is pressed attempting to edit non-editable content of a cell, even if it has `Selectable -> False`. Personally, I just got frustrated by dozens of cells generated while developing the widget after rerunning its code multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing a comment:

> I have Graphics that a user can draw on. But it can be anything, this problem happens with any control if a key is pressed attempting to edit non-editable content of a cell, even if it has Selectable -> False. Personally, I just got frustrated by dozens of cells generated while developing the widget after rerunning its code multiple times

I'd do:

```
print = NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[]
, Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@#, "Output", CellTags -> "print"]
] &
```

```
NotebookDelete@Cells[CellTags -> "print"];
print @ Graphics @ Disk[] 
(* your ui instead of graphics, "printed" output will always be deleted even if
cell style or options change *)
```